# Selecting minimum column value and querying only the distinct corresponding row

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm trying to query a table with multiple non-unique foreign keys. I want to select the 'store' with the minimum distance (miles) So there could be multiple stores with different distances and I want a distinct row with the lowest miles

```
SELECT
    m.store1, m.miles, mitable.region, mitable.terminal, mitable.city, mitable.state
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         store1, MIN (miles) as miles
     FROM
         mitable
     GROUP BY
         region, store1) m
INNER JOIN  
    mitable ON m.store1 = mitable.store1
            AND m.miles = mitable.miles
```

Right now this is pulling the wrong data for me... I'm stuck!

Comment: could you please show some sample data and expected result;here is one example to look at:https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 1):

Just use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by store1 order by miles asc) as seqnum
      from mitable t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

EDIT:

If you want the row with the fewest miles, then you can do:

```
select top 1 t.*
from mitable t
order by miles asc;
```

This returns exactly one row.  If you want multiple rows in the case of ties, then use `top with ties`.

Comment: This is still not returning my desired lowest value . I notice on some rows it returns the second or third lowest .

Answer (score 0):

Yo are close. Just delete `region` in `group by`

```
SELECT
    m.store1, m.miles, mitable.region, mitable.terminal, mitable.city, mitable.state
FROM 
    (SELECT 
         store1, MIN (miles) as miles
     FROM
         mitable
     GROUP BY
        store1
        --region 
   ) m
INNER JOIN  
    mitable ON m.store1 = mitable.store1
            AND m.miles = mitable.miles
```

Comment: same problem as above. I have situations where it's still not pulling the correct row. Could it be that I need to make it a float?

Comment: Show sample data please I can help then